# finding error in command line

Tags: command-line

I am trying to run some kind of programm using command line, but I got an error.
The command line is:

`quantisnp2.exe --outdir D:\output\ --config "C:\Program files\QuantiSNP\params.dat" --levels "C:\Program files\QuantiSNP\levels.dat" --sampleid CNV1 --gender female --emiters 10 --Lsettings 2000000 --doXcorrect --genotypes --gcdir D:\gc\ --input-files C:\Program files\CNV1.txt`

```
QuantiSNP:Single-file mode input find.
QuantiSNP:Processing file: C:|Program
QuantiSNP:Local CG content directory specified. Local CG content correction will be used.
??? Error using ==>textread at 167
File not found.
Error in ==> quantisnp2 at 293
```

Comment: How to find where the error are in command line? Did I write something wrong in command line?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'd be looking at is the unquoted `C:\Program files\CNV1.txt` at the end of the command (all your other ones are quoted).

There's a good chance that's being treated as *two* arguments, `C:\Program` and `files\CNV1.txt`.

You may also want to check the spelling of `emiters`, I'm pretty certain the correct English word would be `emitters` though, of course, this could be a case of the QuantiSNP developers not knowing how to spell :-)